# Missing vagrant boxes in VirtualBox

Tags: macos, vagrant, virtualbox

I want to change some options for my vagrant virtual machine.

I opened virtualbox, but I don't see any running virtual machines. How it can be ? I did the same operation on another computer (windows 10) - no problem, I see virtual machine in VirtualBox.

OS: Mac OS X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

could it be you have multiple install of Virtualbox ?

you can find out by the following:

- startup your vagrant machine : `vagrant up`
- check your vm is running through virtual box : `VBoxManage list runningvms --long`
  you should get all your VM information (Name, UUID etc)
- check which virtual box is getting used :

  ```
  fhenri@machine:~/project/examples/vagrant/ubuntu$ which VBoxManage
  /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage
  ```
- from this same folder, startup virtual box (in my case it was `/usr/local/bin/`

  ```
  fhenri@machine:~/project/examples/vagrant/ubuntu$ /usr/local/bin/VirtualBox
  ```

It should start up virtual box app (UI) and your VM should be there.

In the weird case it would not be there, you could still import from the `Config file` property given by command `VBoxManage list runningvms --long`

Comment: On my Mac I have some troubles with rights. If I run sudo /usr/local/bin/VirtualBox - it works, if I run from Applications - I don't have access to my VMs from VirtualBox. :(

Comment: hum .. how did you install virtualbox ? and which version of mac do you run

Comment: These problems appeared already after installing VirtualBox. Our admins did some tasks with my PC and broke my user, restored him, and after that I have periodically troubles with permissions.
OS X 10.9.5

Comment: I am having this problem also, but `VBoxManage list runningvms --long` doesn't show my vagrant boxes and `VBoxManage list vms` doesn't either.

Comment: Same issue as OP. It worked on my previous installation of MacOS now it just won't add vagrant boxes to VirtualBox and `/usr/local/VirtualBox` and `/usr/local/bin/VBoxManage` points to the correct `/Applications/VirtualBox`

Comment: @dezza not sure what the issue is, what is the message when you run `vagrant up` ? maybe you should add your own question with the full output

Comment: @FrédéricHenri there's no errors. Thats what makes it frustrating. "vagrant box add" just doesn't do `VBoxManage import` and `/usr/local/bin/VBoxManage` points to the correct location e.g. `/Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxManage`

Comment: @dezza `vagrant box add` does not do `VBoxManage import`, adding a box just copy box files in `.vagrant` folder but there's no VM at this stage, only when you run `vagrant up` it will create the VM and run `VBoxManage` command

Comment: @FrédéricHenri are you absolutely sure? I'll have to test at my home workstation where I have it working. So if I use this combined with kitchen only when `kitchen converge` is run it should import it right? At this stage it will fail with repeated SSH-connection errors and I believe this is because it thought it was added with `vagrant box add`